# Confusion between OOP approaches among different developers

Tags: c#, class, oop

I have been developing web apps using .net and c# from last 1 year, but there is some confusion going on in my mind regarding OOP principals implementation.

1) What i learned from the object oriented books was that every class should have its specific methods, but when i came across the code of a senior developer, i saw that the developer has created a separate business layer with a business layer class containing all the methods of all the classes.

Is this approach of using separate business class containing all the methods being used in our app is justified by any design pattern or by any other resource, or it is just an awful design?

Please elaborate your answer in detail as this can also helps other newbies out there...

Comment: Perhaps better on Programmers.SE

Comment: For 1.) Do you mean that the classes only hold state information (properties) with no methods, and that there's a giant static functions class in the Business Layer? If so, you should get in touch with Jeff Atwood over at Coding Horrors...

Comment: Two very different questions there, it might be worth breaking (2) into its own question.

Comment: `"a business layer class containing all the methods of all the classes"` - This sounds *terrible*.  But I can't help but wonder if maybe you're not describing it accurately.  If the description is accurate, that senior developer is destructive to the business value of the code.  If it's not accurate, then it's not clear what's going on.  Maybe you can provide some code as an example?

Comment: @David actually that approach from a senior developer forced me to re-think about my object oriented principals, so i thought of posting a question on stack overflow. I can describe you the architecture of our application as it was a simple inventory management built using entity framework, there were model classes containing only data, and then there was a business layer having only one class containing all the methods which are being used in our system...

Comment: @AsadMalik: That is indeed an awful, awful design.  It's not taking advantage of OO principles at all.  The "models" are just bare DTOs with no meaningful business functionality, and that single "business layer" class is a kind of dumping ground for unorganized procedural code.  If you learn anything from this architecture, learn not to do it like that.

Comment: @David so i am coming to a conclusion that models classes should contain class specific methods?

Comment: Asad, read about SOLID.  Specifically the "S".  Each class should contain only properties/methods relevant to _that_ class.  A single business layer class with _every_ method for _every_ class is just nasty.... NASTY I SAY!

Comment: What if i show this thread to my boss? Senior developer is in trouble... :P

Comment: @AsadMalik: Indeed.  Objects should encapsulate the functionality specific to that object.  A `Car` object might have a method called `Drive()` which, when invoked, modifies the state of the car.  Having something like `SomeRandomDumpingGround.DriveCar(Car carInstance)` is a mess, and it places the responsibility of the `Car` object in the wrong place.  Separation of concerns and placing responsibilities where they meaningfully belong is key.

Comment: From [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/)'s [Anemic Domain Model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) article: *the more common mistake is to give up too easily on fitting the behavior into an appropriate object, gradually slipping toward procedural programming.*.

Comment: @David I don't understand why everyone is saying it's an awful design. When dealing with an ORM, POCOs **never** contain any behavior, there are just here to hold the data. The business layer is responsible of dealing with the business method (such as CRUD as well as any other business operation). I would like to provide a more detailed answer to your question, but I can't as it's closed.

Comment: @ken2k: Your experience with ORMs seems to be pretty limiting to the objects that are being relationally mapped, then.  They may separate DTO functionality from business functionality by means of partial classes, but the business objects themselves should indeed encapsulate their business functionality.  DTOs alone aren't business objects, they're just data structures.

Comment: This is wrong, why this question was closed, i changed my question and i think it can be answered now..

Answer (score 1):

Architecture is an art not a science.  There are good architectures and bad architectures, but there is not a single correct architecture.

For example your Senior developer may have created a Facade (design pattern) on top of your more complicated data access layer to simplify data access.  For instance you could have a dozen entities for ordering a product, and you would like to create a facade for everything you need to do while ordering a product.

Just look at the architecture and try to analyze yourself if you think it could be better.  The more architecture you know the better your judgment will be, but architecture is rarely black and white.

Also, just because someone is senior it doesn't necessarily mean that they know what they are doing or that they don't make mistakes.

Also, Inheritance can be done in EF:
[Inheritance in EF](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0):

there is no single architecture one can follow, for example when building strictly SOA systems it is VERY common to have model classes that are only data, no methods whatsoever.  Whereas all the business logic classes exist in a different namespace.  Furthermore when you send your domain classes over the wire you will typically create dedicated classes for that purpose in a different assembly dedicated to the SOA.

The architecture I describe above is directly from the Microsoft Architecture Guidance package for VS.

Comment: OK, can u elaborate me that what should be the architecture for an online inventory management and reporting system?

Comment: Let's start with what you are thinking?  However MVC is a great model to follow, however MODEL for the VIEW is not the same as the Domain model, in other words you should try and separate your model from it's view requirements, design your model from the business perspective.  For the view create dedicated VIEW MODEL classes, look at MVVM.